# Should I use in 'has' or 'have' in sentence

Tags: grammar

If I have a sentence that reads: ''Consequently, industrial use and academic research have employed the product on this basis.''

Should I be using ''research *has* employed'' or ''research *have* employed''?

Comment: Presumably it's the *research**er**s*, not the *research* who *employ*...?

Comment: This is also a duplicate of one from the other day, I just need to find it.

Comment: On re-reading.  The subject is "industrial use and research".  This is plural.

Comment: Hmm, the duplicate I was thinking of was asking about "was/were"; no longer sure whether I should flag.

Comment: The term 'research' is simply being used as a generic to mean researchers in general.

Comment: @HopFrog: The answer to your question is "have", but your sentence is nonsense. "Industrial use" cannot employ anything, and "Consequently" and "on this basis" mean the same thing. Give us a hint of the context, and we'll help you get it right ;)

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the sentence comprises two things - "use" and "research", and hence it is in the plural, and requires a plural form of the verb, viz. "have".